# Рекурсивный запрос в yii в сортировке?

Tags: php, yii

есть запрос Postgres

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp1 ( id,id_parent,name,PATH, LEVEL, myname  ) AS (
SELECT T1.id,T1.id_parent, T1.name, CAST (T1.id AS VARCHAR (50)) as PATH, 1 , 
CAST (T1.name AS VARCHAR (255)) as myname
    FROM t_department T1 WHERE T1.id_parent = 5 and t1.type::int = 1 and t1.hidden = 0
union
select T2.id, T2.id_parent, T2.name, CAST ( temp1.PATH ||'->'|| T2.id AS VARCHAR(50)) ,LEVEL + 1 ,
CAST ((repeat(' _ ', LEVEL+1)||T2.name) AS VARCHAR(255))
     FROM t_department T2 INNER JOIN temp1 ON( temp1.id= T2.id_parent))
select * from temp1 
ORDER BY PATH  desc LIMIT 100
```

получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в модели могу изобразить

```
$dataReader = $connection->createCommand($sql)->query();
$rows = $dataReader->readAll();
for($i = 0, $cnt = count($rows); $i < $cnt; $i++) //формируем столбцы
{
    $id[] = $rows[$i]['id'];
}
        $criteria->addInCondition('id', $id);
```

так я отдам id которые отображать.

а как вывести имена с отступами и сделать сортировку по пути

---

### UPD

сделал так

```
 public function primaryKey()
        {
                return 'id';
        }
```

генератор позволил создать контролеры и вьюшки.

но приобращении ко вьюшке получаю

> CException
>
> Mymodel содержит неверное правило проверки. Правило должно иметь имя и включать элементы для проверки.

Answer (score 1):

Перекройте у модели метод `primaryKey()`.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#primaryKey()-detail